# Floating action button on top of map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I want to Place floating action button on top of map fragment.
My map fragment is completely filled the entire screen. When I place a floating action button it is not coming on top of map fragment
Please refer the image attached:

[image: map fragment with search bar]

Please find layout code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <!--<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bell32"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/alarm_on_switch"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bell32"
                />-->

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:context="reminder.locrem.com.locationreminder.MapsActivity"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/done"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:elevation="4dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: I have edited the question to add xml code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use FrameLayout to acieve what you want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="reminder.locrem.com.locationreminder.MapsActivity" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/done"
                app:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @sasikanth kindly upvote if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can try to this code..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="myLocationCall"
    android:rotation="0" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi sasikanth if this can help you then please ACCEPT and UPVOTE this..thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion but it did not help i posted my layout xml code as well please let me know if there are any mistakes in that

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement, I used android material floating action button.

The button came with material design.

The trick was to add the button inside the fragment and then change the margin gravity accordingly.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:context=".ui.Maps.MapsActivity" >

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />
        </fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the **android:layout_gravity="top|right"**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />

          <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top|right"
              android:layout_margin="16dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
              app:layout_anchor="@id/lvToDoList"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```